# Error in memory allocation of a struct field

Tags: c, struct, memory-management

Attached minimal example:

```
struct MyStruct {
    int a;
};

void testFun(struct MyStruct* testStruct) {
    printf("a: %s", testStruct->a);
}; 

void main(){
    struct MyStruct testStruct = { .a = 1 };
    testFun(&testStruct);
};
```

which throughs me out with: **Exception thrown at 0x791428BC (ucrtbased.dll) in test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000001.**

What I am missing here?

Comment: What compiler are you using? Didn't it tell you about mismatch between format string and parameter?

Answer (score 4):

`%s` is for printing strings (sequences of characters terminated by a null-character) and it expects a pointer `char*` to the first element of the string.

You should use `%d` to print an `int` in decimal.

Answer (score -2):

Try the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct MyStruct {
    int a;
};

void testFun(struct MyStruct* testStruct) {
    printf("a: %d\n\n", testStruct->a);
}; 

int main(){
    struct MyStruct testStruct = { .a = 1 };
    testFun(&testStruct);
    return(0);
};
```

Output should look like the following text:

```
a: 1
```

Comment: For future reference, this answer was discussed on Meta: [Why am I receiving downvotes when little has changed in my answering style?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407867/12892553)